# StringList for C# in Dllimport

Tags: c#, dllimport

I am working on C#. I need to use an API exported from an unmanaged dll. The API in the dll is using Stringlist* as datatype for one argument. How can I define my DllImport in the C# project so that I can comfortably pass the equivalent data from C# to the unmanaged code.

I tried using List, ArrayList, string[]. None worked. I am getting undefined exceptions on executing the API.

I would be thankful if anyone could assist me with this issue.

Comment: What is `Stringlist*`? Is that a typedef to char**, or char*[], or something like that? Is it a C++ class? Is it a C struct?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the `System.Collections.Specialized.StringCollection` is the class, you are looking for. I hope, this will help